# dowloading photos uploaded as google form answer with a name

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-forms

I have created a google form where I collect info about workers (name famil photo etc...).
I want to download all photos uploaded through the form to my PC but I want each photo downloaded to have a name suitable to the name and family answers that the worker submitted , i.e. _.
This will be used to produce magnetic cards automatically without the need to go over each one and choose his image manually.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading file, you can use the method specified in the documentation.

> The Drive API allows you to upload file data when [creating](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create) or
>   [updating](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update) a [File](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/) resource.
>
> You can send upload requests in any of the following ways:
>
> - Simple upload: `uploadType=media`. For quick transfer of a small file    (5 MB or less). To perform a simple upload, refer to
>     [Performing a    Simple Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/simple-upload).
> - Multipart upload: uploadType=multipart. For quick transfer of a small    file (5 MB or less) and metadata describing the file, all in
>     a single    request. To perform a multipart upload, refer to
>     [Performing a    Multipart Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/multipart-upload).
> - Resumable upload: uploadType=resumable. For more reliable transfer,    especially important with large files. Resumable uploads are a good
>     choice for most applications, since they also work for small files at 
>     the cost of one additional HTTP request per upload. To perform a
>     resumable upload, refer to [Performing a Resumable Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload).
>
> Most Google API client libraries implement at least one of the
>   methods. Refer to the client library documentation for additional
>   details on how to use each of the methods.

Then you can [manipulate your metadata](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/file#top_of_page),

> Much of the information you'll need to get started inserting and
>   retrieving files is detailed in the [Files reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files). Here are a
>   few more important considerations for naming files and working with
>   metadata like thumbnails and indexable text.

Next, here is how to [Specify file names and extensions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/file#specifying_file_names_and_extensions)

> Apps should specify a file extension in the title property when
>   inserting files with the API. For example, an operation to insert a
>   JPEG file should specify something like `"name": "cat.jpg"` in the
>   metadata.
>
> Subsequent `GET` requests include the read-only `fileExtension`
>   property populated with the extension originally specified in the name
>   property. When a Google Drive user requests to download a file, or
>   when the file is downloaded through the sync client, Drive builds a
>   full filename (with extension) based on the title. In cases where the
>   extension is missing, Google Drive attempts to determine the extension
>   based on the file's MIME type.